# Why does ClientBase Dispose need to throw on faulted state?

Tags: c#, .net

Why does ClientBase Dispose need to throw on faulted state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably because you need to [`Abort` it first](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.communicationstate.aspx):

> An object in the Faulted state is not
>   closed and may be holding resources.
>   The Abort method should be used to
>   close an object that has faulted. If
>   Close is called on an object in the
>   Faulted state, a
>   CommunicationObjectFaultedException is
>   thrown because the object cannot be
>   gracefully closed.

From [`ClientBase.Dispose` doco](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340248.aspx):

> Closes the client object.

You are probably getting `CommunicationObjectFaultedException` because you are calling `Dispose` (which calls `Close`) before aborting. Abort, then Dispose and you should be OK.

Comment: Wow, +1 for psychic powers ;-)